# show and hide UserControls based on button click

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I have 3 UserControls and my MainWindow. In my UserControl3 I have two buttons (button1 & button2).

1. I need to add the UserControl3 to my MainWindow when we start the application
2. If I click button1, usercontrol1 should appear on my mainwindow, if i click button2, usercontrol2 should appear on my mainwindow.

How to do this? Have you an example of this?

Comment: You should name your controls.

Comment: @SLaks Telling him to name his controls does not answer his question.

Comment: @gun You need to explain how you want UserControl1 and 2 created. Are the created in code-behind? Are they content controls bound to data in the view model? When you want them to appear, are you saying you want to just toggle the visibility? Or are you wanting to actually create an instance and display it? Please see ["How do I ask a good question"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: As asked, your question is far too broad. Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that clearly shows what you've tried so far, and explain what that code does and why that's different from what you want it to do. Please explain why `UserControl3` is not simply part of the XAML from the outset. Please explain how visually the other two `UserControl` objects should be shown/hidden. What should the UI actually do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right from your `MainWindow.xaml`, create two buttons at the bottom of the window, and add a `Stack Panel` at the center of the window.

...
Or copy the following `XAML` markup in the `<Grid>` tag:

```
<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="UserControl1_Btn" Content="UserControl1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,289,0,10" Width="153"/>
    <Button x:Name="UserControl2_Btn" Content="UserControl2" Margin="354,0,10,10" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
    <StackPanel x:Name="StackPanelFixed_SP" Margin="10,10,10,47"/>
</Grid>
```

After that, create **TWO** User Controls from **Solution Explorer** by right-clicking the project name, then Add -> User Control... (Do that twice)

[image]

Add some content in the two User Controls anything you like, for this example I will use the background color so that you can tell whether if it was **UserControl1** or **UserControl2**.

**UserControl1** will be colored to **BLACK**

**UserControl2** will be colored to **RED**

Add a click event to the first button and add the following lines of code:

[image]

```
    StackPanelFixed_SP.Children.Clear();
    UserControl1 UC1 = new UserControl1();
    StackPanelFixed_SP.Children.Add(UC1);
    UC1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
```

For the second button, add the following line of code:

```
    StackPanelFixed_SP.Children.Clear();
    UserControl2 UC2 = new UserControl2();
    StackPanelFixed_SP.Children.Add(UC2);
    UC2.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
```

Finally, you will have a program that will start with **TWO Buttons** (one on the bottom-left, and the other on the bottom right) with a blank background. After clicking one of the buttons, you will get part of the UI being colored (I know it sounds stupid, but I'm trying to make a point for using the User Controls).